# SwiftUI VStack align child items to top

Tags: swiftui, vstack

Kindly help, I have a view that uses a CustomView. In Custom view there are 2 lists in vertical Stack, the issue here is there's always a space between 2 lists even when using Spacer?

```
struct CustomView: View {
 var body: some View{
        VStack(spacing:0) {
        List(0..<2){ item in
               TestView()
           }
        
        List(0..<2){ item in
               TestView()
           }
       }
    .background(Color.blue)
}

 struct TestView: View {

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
        .padding()
        .padding()
   }
}
```

Comment: Use `VStack(spacing: 0)`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65446995/12299030.

Comment: tried it already!

Comment: Presumably, you want each `List` to be scrolling (otherwise, I'd think you'd just use ForEach`), but to shrink in height to the smallest necessary view if it's smaller than 50% of the parent view? And otherwise scroll? It might help to describe your desired output more specifically.